# Arcmap Combine tool output missing one field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, spatial-analyst

I have sets of two rasters in Arcmap with identical extents and resolutions, but different values. I previously have used Combine in the Local toolset of Spatial Analyst to create a new raster with new values, but that retains the values of the two inputs as separate fields in the output. Now, only the value from the first listed raster is retained. What gives?

Comment: Are both your input rasters integer? If doubles/floats they get truncated. Does the raster whose values are not being written to output have more than 65536 unique values, and if so have you gone into the options and increased the cap on this value? These two issues are noted in the tool help: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000007r000000